# Общий численный делитель

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Есть два числа (к примеру, *1200* и *800*). Как найти их общий делитель? То есть, как найти число, на которое можно поделить эти два и чтобы после деления вышло целое число?

*Детальное описание:*
Берём два числа: *1200* и *800*. Далее нужно найти число, после деления на которое выйдет целое число. К примеру, *200* (*1200 / 200 = 6* - целое число; *800 / 200 = 4* - целое число).

Попробовал сделать циклом, но толкового не вышло. Оно не всегда находит число.

```js
function isInteger(num) {
  return (num ^ 0) === num;
};

var num = [1228, 862],
    divider = null;

for(var i = 80; i < num[0]; i++){
  if( isInteger(num[0] / i) && isInteger(num[1] / i) ){
    divider = i;
  };
};

console.log( divider );
```

Так как найти больший делитель, после которого будет целое число?

Comment: почему проверка начинается с 80? если поставишь с 1 и выведешь все возможные делители - твой код выведет только _1_ и _2_

Comment: @Other, он не НОК, а НОД хочет

Comment: @Grundy, суть в том, что если будет 1 или 2, то это будут очень маленькие числа... нужно где-то 80 и больше

Comment: @Grundy, при том заметил, что если указать 1200 и 800, то оно выдаёт 400, а не 200 или 100

Comment: @Yuri, ну вообще _не все_ пары чисел имеют делители 80 и больше

Comment: _при том заметил, что если указать 1200 и 800, то оно выдаёт 400, а не 200 или 100_ - потому что ты не прерываешь цикл, когда хоть что-то нашел, ты крутишь все возможные варианты, до первого числа и выводишь _последнее_ найденное

Comment: @Grundy, думал break сразу рвёт. Как в начале оборвать? Можешь своё решение предложить.. цикл мне не очень нравится

Comment: Что за странный алгоритм? НОД обычно ищется делением с остатком.

Comment: @Akina, вы про `isInteger` ?

Comment: @Yuri я про алгоритм Евклида. Поделить бОльшее на меньшее с остатком. Если остаток 0, то результат = меньшему, иначе заменить большее на остаток и повторить.

Comment: @Yuri, по задаче непонятно, нужен ли тебе наибольший общий делитель, или первый попавшийся или первый попавшийся после больше определенного числа

Comment: @Grundy, больший

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм Еклида для нахождения наибольшего общего делителя:

```
var num = [1228, 862];

while(num[0] !== 0 && num[1] !== 0){
  if(num[0] > num[1]){
     num[0] = num[0] % num[1];
  }else{
     num[1] = num[1] % num[0];
  }
}

var divider = num[0] + num[1];
```

Comment: может быть наибольшего?

Comment: При выводе сложить не постеснялся, а чего постеснялся перемножить при проверке?

Comment: @Grundy, вы правы, ошибся

Comment: @Akina, это чтобы не проверять какой из них равен нулю

Comment: @KirillSemenov, имелось в виду условие цикла. `while(num[0]*num[1])`