# Сокращение дроби

Tags: jquery

Начал изучать jquery, вот хочу написать скрипт для перевода десятичных дробей в обыкновенные.

Пока получился и вот такой код.

```js
var number = 40.1250223;
alert(number + " Вводимое число");
var remain = number % 1;
var remainFixed = remain.toFixed(4);
alert(remainFixed + " Сокращенная нецелая часть числа");
var factor = 10000;
var numberFixed = number.toFixed();
alert(numberFixed + " Число до запятой");
var decimalNumber = remainFixed * factor;
alert(decimalNumber + " Число после запятой");
var wholeNumber = numberFixed + decimalNumber;
alert(wholeNumber + " Целое число");
var numerator = wholeNumber;
var denominator = factor;
alert(numerator + ' / ' + denominator + " Дробное число");
```

Дальше, насколько я представляю, нужно с помощью цикла вычислить наибольший общий делитель и сократить число, но как реализовать пока не пойму.

Comment: как найти делитель, или как сократить?

Comment: как найти делитель. Если не знаете как - как бы вы искали...? В каком диапазоне он лежит? Если "влоб" то это число межно 2 и min(numerator,denominator) верно? Переберите в цикле и найдите число при котором numerator %число и denominator%число даст ноль одновременно.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну логично же что как найти делитель) чтобы сократить нужно же просто на него поделить)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Общий численный делитель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644730/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Comment: `numberFixed` у тебя не `number`, а `string`

Comment: @nick_n_a это потому что .toFixed строку возвращает?